# Android Multiple Activities

Tags: android

I have two activities in my app. There is a `ListView` in the first one and the second one is meant to represent the details for each item of the `ListView`. The problem is that when I call the second `Activity` it always opens the same thing but not a new one for each item. Any suggestions?

This is how I changed the calling of the second activity but it is not really working for me.

```
if (item.getTitle().equals("Open")){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that activity singleTop and pass the flag clear top when you are starting it.

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="SomeLabel"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

in your calling Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

You could also be finishing the second activity by calling `finish();` when the user leaves it.